# inspect.getmembers in order?

Tags: python

> ```
> inspect.getmembers(object[, predicate])
> ```
>
> Return all the members of an object in a list of `(name, value)` pairs sorted by name.

I want to use this method, but I don't want the members to be sorted. I want them returned in the same order they were defined. Is there an alternative to this method?

---

My use case is creating a form like so:

```
class RegisterForm(Form):
    username = Field(model_field='username', filters=validators.minlength(3))
    password1 = Field(model_field='password', widget=widgets.PasswordInput)
    password2 = Field(widget=widgets.PasswordInput)
    first_name = Field(model_field='first_name')
    last_name = Field(model_field='last_name')
    address = SubForm(form=AddressForm, model_field='address')
```

I want the fields to be rendered in the same order they are defined.

Answer (score 16):

You can dig around to find the line number for methods, not sure about other members:

```
import inspect

class A:
    def one(self):
        pass

    def two(self):
        pass

    def three(self):
        pass

    def four(self):
        pass

def linenumber_of_member(m):
    try:
        return m[1].__func__.__code__.co_firstlineno
    except AttributeError:
        return -1

a = A()
l = inspect.getmembers(a)
print(l)
l.sort(key=linenumber_of_member)
print(l)
```

prints:

```
[('__doc__', None), ('__module__', '__main__'), ('four', <bound method A.four of <__main__.A instance at 0x0179F738>>), ('one', <bound method A.one of <__main__.A instance at 0x0179F738>>), ('three', <bound method A.three of <__main__.A instance at 0x0179F738>>), ('two', <bound method A.two of <__main__.A instance at 0x0179F738>>)]
[('__doc__', None), ('__module__', '__main__'), ('one', <bound method A.one of <__main__.A instance at 0x0179F738>>), ('two', <bound method A.two of <__main__.A instance at 0x0179F738>>), ('three', <bound method A.three of <__main__.A instance at 0x0179F738>>), ('four', <bound method A.four of <__main__.A instance at 0x0179F738>>)]
```

Comment: This doesn't account for functions being imported from somewhere else, it will look at their line numbers, which will be unrelated to the current file. For example if you had `import os` then in your class you did `five = os.makedirs`, its `.__code__.co_firstlineno` would be [its line number in `os`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c1a3f9a9cbf5cf96ced5a2b16572cba7be964377/Lib/os.py#L200) (current 200 for me on Python 3.9), not in your module. You'll have to [filter those members out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65251833/get-all-defined-functions-in-python-module).

Answer (score 5):

The attributes (methods and other members) of an object is usually looked up through an object's special `__dict__` attribute which is a standard Python dictionary. It doesn't guarantee any specific ordering.

If an attribute is not found in the object's `__dict__` the class's is searched instead (where methods usually reside) and so on until the whole inheritance chain has been traversed.

Here is some custom inspection done in the interactive prompt to illustrate this (Python 3.1):

```
>>> class Klass():
...     def test(self):
...             pass
...
>>> k = Klass()
>>> k.__dict__
{}
>>> k.__class__.__dict__.items()
[('test', <function test at 0x00000000024113C8>), ('__dict__', <attribute '__dic
t__' of 'Klass' objects>), ('__module__', '__main__'), ('__weakref__', <attribut
e '__weakref__' of 'Klass' objects>), ('__doc__', None)]
```

Would I have put a constructor (`__init__`) in Klass and set an attribute through `self` it would've shown up in `k.__dict__`.

You can circumvent this by using a custom metaclass. The documentation contains an example which does exactly what you want.

See the bottom of this page for the [OrderedClass example](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation).

*Don't know what version of Python you have so I assumed latest.*

Comment: Python 2.6. So I have to use a metaclass to keep the members in order?

Comment: @Mark: I should've added, you still can't use inspect or dir, since the `type` object will use a straight up dictionary in the end. But they circumvent that through a custom attribute on subclasses called `members` which is ordered.

Comment: @Skurmedel: Couldn't we explicitly replace `__dict__` with an ordered dict No matter though, I'm fine having an ordered member variable.

Comment: @Mark: Sadly no, I think `type` is expecting a `dict` and it seems that if I pass an OrderedDict it will end up a dict anyway, perhaps through `dict(x)`. I need to read up some more, but maybe `type` is implemented in C and needs the default dictionary type.

Comment: @Mark: Python 2.6.5 source for `type`: http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r265/Objects/typeobject.c?view=markup I've been reading the (frankly huge) function `type_new` and I think it's copying the passed in dictionary to a new `dict`, which would explain why it ends up as a `dict` no matter what in my tests.

Comment: Well that's dumb :( So hard to do something that ought to be so simple!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think Python 2.6 has a `__prepare__` method, so I can't swap out the default `dict` for an ordered one. I can, however, replace it using a `metaclass` and the `__new__` method. Instead of inspecting line numbers, I *think* its easier and more efficient to just use a creation counter.

```
class MetaForm(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['fields'] = OrderedDict(
            sorted(
                [(name, attrs.pop(name)) for name, field in attrs.items() if isinstance(field, Field)],
                key=lambda t: t[1].counter
            )
        )
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class Form(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaForm

class Field(object):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = Field.counter
        Field.counter += 1
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have different classes of objects and want to maintain order between all of them... I guess I could make them all inherit from the same `OrderedObject` though.

Comment: Starting with CPython 3.6 and all other Python implementations starting with 3.7, the builtin `dict` is ordered by insertion so you don't need to use `OrderedDict` for this

Comment: This is the most resilient solution IMO, and it also works for fields scattered in multiple classes in an inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the builtin function [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) as an alternative for `inspect.getmembers` that returns members in the order they were defined:

```
>>> class RegisterForm:
...     username = ""
...     password1 = ""
...     password2 = ""
...     first_name = ""
...     last_name = ""
...     address = ""
...
>>> list(vars(RegisterForm).keys())
['__module__', 'username', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address', '__doc__']
```

This works starting with CPython 3.6 and all other Python implementations starting with Python 3.7, because `dict`s are now ordered by insertion, which means the underlying `__dict__` property of a class (which is what `vars()` returns) is ordered.

Answer (score 2):

```
members = []
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module):
    source, start_line = inspect.getsourcelines(obj)
    members.append([name, obj, start_line])

def _line_order(value):
    return value[2]

members.sort(key = _line_order)
```

Answer (score 1):

In reference to Ned Batchelder's answer above, in Python 3 line numbers of a method m can be gotten with `m.__func__.__code__.co_firstlineno`

[`inspect` — Inspect live objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)