# Ordering class methods without instantiation

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Related**: [inspect.getmembers in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169014/inspect-getmembers-in-order)

**Background**: I'm trying to build a tool that creates a Python file according to a certain specification. One option is to give, as input, a Python module that contains an abstract class declaration, and creates a base class that inherits that abstract class but also adds a default implementation to all abstract methods.

For example: say I have the following file, called `Abstract.py` that contains the following:

```
class Abstract(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @abstractmethod
    def first(self):
        pass
    @abstractmethod
    def second(self):
        pass
```

So then the output of my tool would be a file called `BaseClass.py` that contains:

```
class BaseClass(Abstract):
    def first(self):
        pass
    def second(self):
        pass
```

**I want the methods in the `BaseClass` to be in the same order as in `Abstract`.**

My question is: Is there a way to sort the methods according to their appearance without relying on built-in method comparison (which is based on memory address comparison)? I'm also hoping to avoid any kind of file-parsing, if possible.

Please note that I cannot create an instance of `Abstract` so the solution mentioned in the above [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169014/inspect-getmembers-in-order) will not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of class creation in Python2 (that is, when the interpreter just get pass the class body when running a file, which happens in sequence) - the Class itself is created as an object. At this point all variables and methods defined in the class body are passed to a call to "type"  (which is the default metaclass) as a dictionary.

As you know, dictionaries in Python have no ordering, so ordinarily it is impossible in Python2. It is possible in Python 3 because metaclasses can implement a `__prepare__` method which returns the mapping object that will be used to build the class body - so instead of an ordinary dict, `__prepare__` could return an OrderedDict.

However, in your case, all relevant methods are decorated with `@abstractmethod` - we can take advantage of that to not only annotate the methods as abstract, but also mark down the order in which they appear.

You can either wrap the `abstractclass` decorator, or create another decorator and use both. I'd favor a new decorator that would do both things, in order to keep linecount down.

Also, you have to choose *how*  will you keep the order of the methods and make use of it. Ordinarily iterating on the class's attributes will just iterate over a dictionary  (rather a dictionary proxy), which is unorderd- so, you have to have keep a data structure were to keep the ordered methods available, and a way to record this given order. There are are some options there - but maybe, the most direct thing is to annotate the method order in the methods themselves, and retrieve them with a call to built-in `sorted` with an appropriate `key` parameter. Other means would require eithe a class decorator or a custom metaclass to work.

So here is an example of what I wrote about:

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta

class OrderedAbstractMethod(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    def __call__(self,func):
        func._method_order = self.counter
        self.counter += 1
        return abstractmethod(func)

ordered_abstract_method = OrderedAbstractMethod()



class Abstract(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @ordered_abstract_method
    def first(self):
        pass
    @ordered_abstract_method
    def second(self):
        pass
    @ordered_abstract_method
    def third(self):
        pass
    @ordered_abstract_method
    def fourth(self):
        pass


print "Unordered methods: ",[method[0] for method in   Abstract.__dict__.items() if not method[0].startswith("_") ]
# here it printed out -    ['second', 'third', 'fourth', 'first']

print "Ordered methods: ", sorted([method for method in   Abstract.__dict__.items() if not method[0].startswith("_") ], key= lambda m: m[1]._method_order)
```

Comment: Interesting approach. One drawback is that this means I must go ahead and change all the signatures of all the abstract methods I wish to use this with. Still, this may be the best way to go...

Comment: If there are already a lot of classes, you could call your decorator "abstractmethod" as well, and just import it from a place where it is defined as above.