# Get all defined functions in Python module

Tags: python, function, built-in

I have a file `my_module.py` that looks like this:

```
from copy import deepcopy

from my_other_module import foo

def bar(x):
    return deepcopy(x)
```

I want to get a list of all the functions defined *in* `my_module` and not the imported ones, in this case just `[bar]`, not `deepcopy` or `foo`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`inspect.getmembers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) with [`inspect.isfunction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction) and then get all the functions whose `.__module__` property is the same as the module's `.__name__`:

```py
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
from my_project import my_module

functions = [fn for _, fn in getmembers(my_module, isfunction) if fn.__module__ == my_module.__name__]
```